# How to keep module-info.java up to date

Tags: java, module-info

Is there anyway to find out what your module *requires*?

After writing a basic microservice it took some tinkering to work out what I needed to add to my module-info.java.

It was a simple application with a hardcoded endpoint; it seemed rather painful to get it right and I couldn't find anything that could give me any hints what needed to be added. (I ran the application a good few times using the modules but would error as something was missing which wasn't clear what was missing)

I have much bigger microservices that will need converting and can see it being very painful

Comment: *I couldn't find anything that could give me any hints what needed to be added*... there are definitely compile time errors that won't let you work without the `requires` directives if you really require a 3rd party dependency in your module.

Comment: Use [tag:jdeps]

Comment: jdeps has been great and the "question already has answer" was great too. However from what i've seen i cant find a way of knowing what spring automatic modules i need for my module. Explicit modules this seems fine running jdeps on my jar. Any ideas?